# Explicit polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_p$ mapping roots of irreducibles

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

Suppose $a(T)$, $b(T) \in \mathbb{F}_p [T]$ are monic irreducible polynomials of the same degree $d$. The finite fields $\mathbb{F}_p [T] / (a(T))$ and $\mathbb{F}_p [T]/(b(T))$ are isomorphic, so there must exist some degree $d-1$ polynomial $q(T) \in \mathbb{F}_p [T]$ such that $b(T)$ divides $a(q(T))$.

Given $a(T)$ and $b(T)$, how can I construct such a $q(T)$ explicitly/concretely? (without, say, invoking uniqueness-up-to-isomorphism of finite fields) How many such $q(T)$ are there? (there should be $d$, since each such $q(T)$ gives an automorphism of the finite field?)

Comment: I’ve faced this problem from time to time, but I am by no means a specialist in this area. But I don’t know of any other way than to search for a root of $a(x)$ in $\Bbb F_p[T]/(b(T))$. I’ll be interested to see more useful methods than what I say above.

Comment: I agree with @Lubin that search for a root of $a(x)$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[T]/(b(T))$ is one way. If the isomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{F}_p[T]/(a(T)) \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_p[T]/(b(T))$ is given, then $q(T)=\phi(T)$ works. Once you found one $q(T)$, then  $d$ possible $q$'s may be found from repeatedly applying $\sigma$ to $q(T)$  where $\sigma (x) = x^p$.

Comment: See this paper by Lenstra Jr. https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/08d2/7772c539fd16048a25dadb8a500f191d1a5b.pdf